# How do you find a word that derives or is derived from a given word with a different part of speech?

Tags: parts-of-speech, etymology

How do you find a word that derives or is derived from a given word with a different part of speech? Any book or website?

For example, penitent is the adjective of noun penitence with the derivative relationship.
I think nouns penitence and penance are synonym. I was wondering what the adjective for penance with the derivative relationship is ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure you can say one is derived from another. They all come from a common Latin root.

Comment: Surely "a dictionary" would be the obvious answer.  Perhaps you could explain why dictionaries are not suitable for this.

Comment: @JamesK can you explain which dictionary?

Comment: They are not synonyms. You _do_ penance because you _feel_ penitence for something you have done wrong.

Comment: Any dictionary.  You want to find words that are derived from "penitent" so you look in the dictionary at the page with penitent on it and right next to it is the word "penitence".  Dictionary.com lists "nearby words", so this is often possible with an online dictionary as well as a paper one.

Comment: People are being hard on the OP. It's not trivial with all dictionaries. If you look up [penitent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/penitent) in Merriam-Webster it lists penitently under that, but there is no link to [penitence](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/penitence), for instance. The [Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/penitent) has a very long list of all words from the same PIE root, including passion and passive as well as penitential. Looking nearby in a dictionary is probably the easiest solution, but won't work for prefixed forms.

Comment: You can use online dictionary search functions with the first few letters of the root (e.g. "peniten") although [results aren't necessarily what you'd expect](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peniten) and M-W seems to ignore prefixed forms like impenitent.

Comment: @KateBunting thanks. could you be more specific?

Comment: As any dictionary will tell you,  _penitence_ is a feeling of regret that you have done wrong, a _penance_ is something that you do to show how sorry you are. For Catholics, it may be some extra prayers that your priest has told you to say; less formally, it might be something you feel you have to do to make up for what you did wrong.

Comment: You can search at onelook.com using wildcards for any number of or a specific number of unknown characters at chosen locations within a word. For example, try entering \*penit\* If there are too many results, they can be filtered by part of speech or other functions. Results will be links to multiple dictionaries  Of course, the user must exercise judgment in evaluating the results: sometimes unrelated words share common series of letters.

Comment: @KateBunting thanks. Is repentance a synonym of penitence or penance or different from both?

Comment: Why not try looking up all these words in the dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Generally English words in other parts of speech can be formed by adding suffixes to words.  For example the -er suffix can be added to many (not all) verbs to produce an agent noun. Build -> Builder, for example.

Sometimes the suffix is changed for example lenient <--> lenience. Many (but not all) adjectives ending in -ient have a related noun ending in -ience.

You can check if a particular word has has any words that can be formed from it by adding a suffix by checking a dictionary.  For example looking in a dictionary at "build", the next two words are "buildable" and "builder"  (I'm using Cambridge dictionary, but any would do)  And these are indeed two words that have been formed from "build" by adding suffixes.

Various websites have lists of suffixes. For example https://www.learnthat.org/pages/view/suffix.html. But be careful as not every combination of a word+suffix is natural English, or has the expected meaning.  For example "patience" has a predictable related adjective "patient", but that adjective is also used as a noun (meaning a person receiving medical treatment), with a meaning that you wouldn't predict.